# ¿Por qué recibo el error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

Estoy tratando de definir la siguiente función replicando un ejemplo pero me sale esto:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Al parecer es de paréntesis pero no entiendo estoy replicando

```py
def parabolic((x, y, u, v), t): 
    return [u,
            v,
            0,
            -g]            

inicial = [0, 1.4, 10, 10]  #condiciones iniciales [x = 0, y=1.4, u = 10, v = 10]
t_output = np.arange(0, 3, 0.01)
result = odeint(parabolic, inicial, t_output)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sí, tienes un error al definir la función. En python no se usan parentesis dentro de los parámetros de la función. Por lo que la función quedaría así:

```
def parabolic(x, y, u, v, t): 
    return [u,
            v,
            0,
            -g]
```

### Update

Si quieres pasarle una tupla como parámetro, simplemente se pasa como si fuera cualquier otro tipo de dato, aquí un ejemplo:

```
tupla_prueba = (1,2,3,4)
otro_numero = 7 

def my_fun(tupla, b):

    suma = 0
    for n in tupla:
        suma+= n

    suma +=b
    
    return suma


my_fun(tupla_prueba, otro_numero)
```

Comment: exacto. Si quiere definir una tupla como parámetro, debe marcarla dentro del código

Comment: Sería estupendo que ampliaras tu respuesta para mostrar como pasar una tupla y como usarla dentro de la función.

Comment: Si seria bueno por que el ejercicio lo requiere así y no tengo ni idea como hacer